# Before creating a repository on Bitbucket

Tags: github, repository, bitbucket, ticket-system

I have to think of a way to create an approval process on Bitbucket for repositories. 
Before creating a repository, co-worker submits a ticket to get approval from manager to be able to get the "go-ahead create repository" or denied. Is this possible to do?

My manager notified it could be similar to submitting a ticket on Sharepoint.

I have not found any ways by trail and error or from using resources, so I am reaching out to see if anyone else had to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server?

In either case, I don't believe there's a way to provide conditional, temporary permission to create a single repository of a specific name or team/project.

What I would do in your situation is to set up some kind of bot account (whether using a dedicated account, or a selected individual's account in combination with an app password/personal token) that could be triggered by your approval process and would create a specified repo and grant permissions to it to a specified user. Depending on the tools you're using it's a pretty open ended solution space, but the API calls for Bitbucket Cloud and/or Server should be reasonably straight forward to achieve this, so it's just matter of figuring out how you would trigger and run such an automation.